# Get friends name/id list form graph api into array

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to code some php script that scrap my friends ids and names but I am stuck at how could I get the graph api results into an array.

get url :

```
https://graph.fb.me/me/friends?access_token=EAAC2lsALPUwBACYLu4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxAZDZD&limit=5
```

and the result was like this:

[image: Result]

Any suggestion on how to get them into php array and echo them like:

```
    name : friend1
    id   : 12607000
```

Comment: The format of the result you got is called json. You have to use a json->php converter. I think there are plenty available.

Comment: can i do it in php

Comment: could you provide sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = json_decode($json_data);
```

json_decode convert the json into array.

Comment: i have tried json_decode but couldn't but them into an array could you provide a simple code